# Why Does "yes" have drastically different performance on different ditros?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, performance

I tested **yes** using **pv** with following command on two different distros :

```
yes | pv > /dev/null
```

Results :

*Ubuntu 16.04 : 5.83GiB/s*

*Centos 7.x : 100MiB/s*

Here is my Specs:

*1st distro : Ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS - VM(VMware Workstation) - 4GB ram - 4 CPU- kernel : 4.4.0-166-generic.x86_64*

*2nd distro : Centos 7.7.1908 (Core) - VM(Vmware Workstation) - 4GB ram
- 4 CPU- kernel : 3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64*

*Vmware workstation 15.5 installed on Windows 10*

I was wondering what is the cause of such difference between these two to write on the ram.

Why is Centos too slow to write on the ram?

or is Ubuntu making mistake on performance monitoring while writing on the ram?

Comment: Can you share complete details how you tested with command and summary output.

Comment: Is this about maintaining IT systems in a business environment?

Comment: @asktyagi yes | pv > /dev/null

Comment: @Marco no this is more like performance tuning of underpinning systems

Comment: Might be better suited and get more interaction on [SU](https://superuser.com) or [UL](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [SO](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I also tested on ubuntu16 and RHEL7.2 but didn't see the major difference, it is just 1-2% difference which is not constant and fluctuating. can you please attach complete screenshot with output of command?

Comment: Found the problem, unfortunately the topic is locked. Perhaps somebody call @womble to unlock the topic. The problem was the version of "yes" shipped with Centos 7.7 which was 8.21 seems pretty outdated, for Ubuntu "yes" version was 8.25. After compiling "yes" version 8.25 for Centos the issues solved.